# Stripe HTML tags in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm looking for fastets way to stripe HTML tags from content in Google Apps Script.

For now I'm using these functions to HTML parsing:

```
function getTextFromHtml(body) {
  return getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(body, true).getElement());
}

function getTextFromNode(x) {
 switch(x.toString()) {
  case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
  case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
  default: return '';
 }
}
```

But for long HTML's this way is so inefficient.

Sample HTML content: http://pastebin.com/FmB4hvN2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would remove all tags from the input.

```
 var text = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the content you want to replace is always wrapped with < and >, you can do

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(someString);
string result = rgx.Replace("<[^>]*>", "");
```